# Polybase - is it possible to truncate over length fields

Tags: azure-synapse, polybase

I've defined my external table definition, but I have one field that could theoretically contain a very long string that I dont care about.

Rather than error out, is it possible to set polybase to truncate long fields that extend over the specified length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today it is not possible to truncate during load. It's a great suggestion. You can file a formal request here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse
This is where we capture feedback from the public. Thanks.